# Is it sin when one sing prayer of other religion(if he goes to convent school)?

Tags: sin, other-religions, christianity

> Vyasa says, '..The rejection of one's own creed, the practice of other
> people's creed, ......- these all have been pronounced by persons
> conversant with duties to be acts that no one should do.’
>
> Mahabharata Santi Parva, Section XXXIV-XXXV

Manu 12.95,12.96 reject ideas against vedas calling them unworthy and false

I want to know in many convent schools where we study, in assemblies , we are supposed to ***sing Christian or any other prayer in assemblies. So,I want to know what our  scripture says about this? Or I must just ignore the act.I.E.not utter a single word in assembly.***

Also ***praying to them would be counted as sin of lying or not like I don't consider them even existent but calling them God.Even existent,I count them as human not devta***

[Opinions are not requested, but Scriptural verses]

Comment: You know that Hinduism is much older than modern Christianity right and there will be no direct verse addressing Christianity in Hinduism, right? The 'creeds' mentioned here are different from 'religions'. Nobody in the Indian subcontinent those times believed in anything apart from Dharma. Even Ravana was a Shiva worshipper. The concept of a religion where idol worship and Hindu Dharma was hated was inconceivable.

Comment: Scriptural evidences from an ancient religion advocating Swadharma   cannot be compared to  later evolved  modern opinion.

Comment: In my opinion, it would not be a sin neither would following Nastika faiths they don't lead to moksha and hence in our scriptures are seen as bad paths of ignorance, but Karma reigns supreme. However, if you are following Dharma, but follow your own especially if you are resolved on the Vedic path, then do not praise other religious figures. Tolerance is good, humbleness is good, but syncretism is horrid.

Comment: @Haridasa means, Is calling fiction God isn't sin of lying ???

Comment: @Hope I don't understand your question, but god is fiction. Ishvara, Brahman, or Devatas are real as per our faith. There is no lying. Of course, Jesus was a real dude, but for us definitely not anything remotely divine.

Comment: But, sin is specifically doing bad action leading to hell and the Bhagavad Gita allows for paths that don't attain moksha to be followed. But, these paths have temporary destinations and eventually lead one forward or backward. There is one supreme path and that is the Vedic path.

Comment: You should simply avoid it. If you are a school going student, and they are making you do a Christian prayer, you may not say it (after all, when such a big crowd is singing, your lack of voice wouldn't be noticeable).

Comment: None of the school teachers (of even a convent school) can also force you to say a Christian prayer, if you are not willing, afaik. That's not within the school rules, afaik. But of course, you should not stop them from doing it, after all they are a Christian school. And you would need to attend the prayer in assembly, as a student. Also, why enrol in a convent school, in the first place? It's not like you can't get good teachers and education in non-convent schools now.

Comment: Anyway, on this matter, you cannot have scriptural verses, because Hindu tradition doesn't care about 'Christianity', etc. It's nothing for us. And we don't uphold 'perennialism'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perennial_philosophy

Comment: According to me, in India, it must not be compulsory for students to attend Christian prayers, even in a convent school. But like, changing the rules, is headache. Even the so-called Hindu govt. currently, wouldn't change the rule, in this matter, because it's 'secular'.  Based on what I know, USA has removed this 'mandatory Christian school prayer' for students, from many of its schools, by considering it unconstitutional. When a mlecchadeśa has taken such a decision, like more than 40 yrs ago, why is Bhārata acting like a weakling?